# Pyqt5 ComboBox sorts data automatically

Tags: python, pyqt5

When i insert a dictionary like `{"B": 1, "A": 2, "D": 3, "C": 4}` into a PyQt5 ComboBox, the dict will be alphabetically sorted by the keys. How can i prevent this and keep the original order?

Example:

```
    dictionary = {"B": 1, "A": 2, "D": 3, "C": 4}
    self.comboBox.addItem("Test", dictionary)
    print(dictionary)
    print(self.comboBox.itemData(0))
```

This outputs:

```
    {'B': 1, 'A': 2, 'D': 3, 'C': 4}
    {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 3}
```

Comment: use `OrderedDict` dict?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I use Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is a bug (or at least an unexpected behavior) caused by the way PyQt5 (and PySide2) stores dictionaries, a workaround is to use OrderedDict:

```py
import collections

dictionary = {"B": 1, "A": 2, "D": 3, "C": 4}
print(dictionary)

self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
self.comboBox.addItem("Test", collections.OrderedDict(dictionary))

d = dict(self.comboBox.itemData(0))

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'B': 1, 'A': 2, 'D': 3, 'C': 4}
{'B': 1, 'A': 2, 'D': 3, 'C': 4}
```